# Integration failed when run

Tags: flutter

I try to solve this problem. My integration test failed when I add the latest package. The error 'vm_service does not support' when I add the latest version. So I try to use integration_test 0.8.1. This package ok but when I try to run flutter show this error. Can't someone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since integration_test does not support null safety, could you try running with this command: flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

Comment: Yes, I try everything. But still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In docs was said:
This package has been moved to the Flutter SDK. Starting with Flutter 2.0, it should be included as:

```
dev_dependencies:
```

integration_test:
sdk: flutter

Why you are trying to set up integration_test?

Comment: I try to put integration_test in dev_dependencies. But still error.

Comment: For my task. That is why I set integration_test.